# Materialize Datepicker Label Does not work

Tags: html, css, forms, material-design, materialize

The label just stays there and doesn't animate into active like it normally should.

```
<div class="col s6">
   <div class="input-field">
        <input id="main-date" class="datepicker">
        <label for="main-date">Select Date</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my CSS

```
.main-date {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

JS Initialization

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(currYear,today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-1),
    maxDate: new Date(currYear,12,31),
    //setDefaultDate: new Date(currYear,today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-1),
    yearRange: [1928, currYear-5],
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd"    
  });
});
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong in the documentation. There's a similar post but I believe that solution is significantly outdated.

I just want it exactly like the one in documentation https://materializecss.com/pickers.html but their example doesn't include the code for the label, and there is no nav for handling labels.

Answer (score 1):

was missing type="text". Can't believe I was stuck on that for so long lol.

Comment: Yeah well, I couldn't find documentation, on materialize's website, there's no code with the label at all :) So I used yours :P thanks.